# Form that shows specific text when certain dropdown option and certain radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom, onchange

Basically I am creating a form and I have looked at onchange with the targetElement toggle but I can't seem to figure it out.

Dropdown: A, B, C

Radio: A, B

If Dropdown A and Radio A is selected then it shows a certain div with text. If Dropdown B and Radio A it shows another set. It will all show and hide with the different variations.

Comment: Show some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not having the privilege of seeing your code, this is one approach that you can take:

```
$('#form_id').on('change', 'select, :radio', function(){
    if( $('select', '#form_id').val() == 'A' && $('input#radio_A', '#form_id').is(':checked') ){
        $('#my_text_div').show();
    }else if(  $('select', '#form_id').val() == 'B' && $('input#radio_B', '#form_id').is(':checked') ){
        $('#my_text_div').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple exemple https://jsfiddle.net/L7bpx59w/1/

```
$("#dropdown , input").change(function()
{
    $(".result").text( "Dropdown '"+$("#dropdown").val()+"' AND Radio '"+$("input:radio").val()+"' are selected" );
});
$("#dropdown").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!

I ended up using this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$('#test').change(function () {
    $('.regInfo').hide();
    if ($('#initial').is(':checked') && $('#spouse').is(':checked')) $('.initialSpouse.regInfo').show(); // Initial + Spouse
    if ($('#initial').is(':checked') && $('#employee').is(':checked')) $('.initialEmployee.regInfo').show(); // Initial + Employee

    if ($('#t').is(':checked') && $('#spouse').is(':checked')) $('.tSpouse.regInfo').show(); // t + Spouse
    if ($('#t').is(':checked') && $('#employee').is(':checked')) $('.tEmployee.regInfo').show(); // t + Employee

    if ($('#p').is(':checked') && $('#spouse').is(':checked')) $('.pSpouse.regInfo').show(); // p + Spouse
    if ($('#p').is(':checked') && $('#employee').is(':checked')) $('.pEmployee.regInfo').show(); // p + Employee
});
});//]]>
```

So i have 6 divs that show different text.